# Is there such thing as boolean pool?

Tags: java

I have two questions and unfortunately I can't find answers.

1. If we declare 1000 boolean variables equals to `true` will all of them have the same reference to `true` literal?
2. Java is pass-by-value so consider the code

   ```
   public class Test {
       public static boolean global;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           foo(false);
           System.out.println(global);
       }

       public static void foo(boolean bar) {
           global = bar;
       }
   }
   ```

In `foo()` method the primitive value of boolean variable will be copied and it means that `global` will have another reference for the literal. Or will Java perform some kind of pool lookup for this and `global` will also reference the same memory location as argument?

Comment: It is declared as static, so there is only one

Comment: The main distinction between _reference_ types and _primitive_ types  is that primitive typed variables will not reference a value; they directly contain the value. That means there is no need for a pool ...

Comment: 1. No, but for Boolean object its true

Comment: Just to clarify: Java is not usually pass-by-value. Java is usually pass-by-reference, it's pass-by-value only with respect to primitive types.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin Oh no. Java uses always [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). In case of reference typed variables the value _is_ the reference. That's it.

Comment: Okay, you're right :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a pool. But only if you use `Boolean` object instead of `boolean` primitive value and if you create it using method `valueof` or `Boolean.TRUE`/`Boolean.FALSE` insteand of a constructor. Check the [Boolean javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)) for reference.

Also, take a look to the [constructor javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean(boolean)). It says:

> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Unless a new instance is required, the static factory valueOf(boolean) is generally a better choice. It is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.